# Cannot Log Into a User Account in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, login

I have used multiple methods to create a new user in Windows 7. But I cannot log in. I am being told that the user name and password are incorrect. I've tried deleting the account and creating a new one. I have tried to change the password but I cannot log into any user account that I create. I can only log in to my administrator account.

Comment: What version of Win7 are you using: Basic, Home, Pro, Ultimate..?

Comment: Assuming you're running Win7 Pro (or better): Run `LusrMgr.msc` -> Users -> Right-click: new user. Set UN & PW, logout then login as the new user, done.

Comment: @Ramhound, but that's not the case, is it? His last line states "I can only log in to my administrator account."

Comment: Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1, freshly updated today.

Comment: Thanks, @Foxy. Have you tried running `LusrMgr.msc` to create a new user yet, as I mentioned in my earlier comment?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that someone, unbeknownst to me, added the computer to our local network. Once I became aware of that, I was able to log on using MACHINE_NAME\username. All is well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try also `.\username` (less typing).

Answer (score 0):

You probably messed up with Policies, maybe the users are in a group which is not allowed to local login. i don't know the english translation but this screenshot may help. run `gpedit.msc` as administrator

[image: gpedit.msc.png]

Comment: It certainly could be the local GP, but I would first check EventVwr to just see what is happening when he's trying to login with a newly created user.